# Certutil.exe connects to external resources

Tags: certificate, x509, certutil

While performing certificate verification the certutil.exe connects to different external resources.
The util freezes for 5-10 seconds on the step CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE, on endentity and even Root certificates.
How it can be disabled and why does it happen?
I copied certutil.exe from another server where no such issue, compared hashes, launched but the same.

Command: `certutil.exe -verify GlobalSign_root.cer`

OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393

External resources it connects:

- a95-101-142-11.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com:http
- map2.hwcdn.net:http
- 80-239-217-59.customer.teliacarrier.com:http
- Others

Procmon64.exe.exe shows who connects: certutil.exe

Command output:

```
C:\Temp\certs>certutil -verify GlobalSign.cer
Issuer:
    CN=GlobalSign
    O=GlobalSign
    OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Name Hash(sha1): f59c687f2418d62a790f7592330756ea85e94707
  Name Hash(md5): 01728e1ecf7a9d86fb3cec8948aba953
Subject:
    CN=GlobalSign
    O=GlobalSign
    OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Name Hash(sha1): f59c687f2418d62a790f7592330756ea85e94707
  Name Hash(md5): 01728e1ecf7a9d86fb3cec8948aba953
Cert Serial Number: 04000000000121585308a2

dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_CONSOLE_TRACE (0x20000000)
dwFlags = CA_VERIFY_FLAGS_DUMP_CHAIN (0x40000000)
ChainFlags = CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT (0x40000000)
HCCE_LOCAL_MACHINE
CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_BASE
-------- CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT --------
ChainContext.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)

SimpleChain.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)

CertContext[0][0]: dwInfoStatus=10c dwErrorStatus=0
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  NotBefore: 3/18/2009 3:00 AM
  NotAfter: 3/18/2029 3:00 AM
  Subject: CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3
  Serial: 04000000000121585308a2
  Cert: d69b561148f01c77c54578c10926df5b856976ad
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_NAME_MATCH_ISSUER (0x4)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_IS_SELF_SIGNED (0x8)
  Element.dwInfoStatus = CERT_TRUST_HAS_PREFERRED_ISSUER (0x100)
  Application[0] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
  Application[1] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
  Application[2] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 Code Signing
  Application[3] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 Secure Email
  Application[4] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8 Time Stamping
  Application[5] = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4 Encrypting File System
  Application[6] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6 IP security tunnel termination
  Application[7] = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7 IP security user

Exclude leaf cert:
  Chain: da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
Full chain:
  Chain: d69b561148f01c77c54578c10926df5b856976ad
------------------------------------
Verified Issuance Policies: All
Verified Application Policies:
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 Server Authentication
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 Client Authentication
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 Code Signing
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4 Secure Email
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8 Time Stamping
    1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.4 Encrypting File System
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.6 IP security tunnel termination
    1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.7 IP security user
Cert is a CA certificate
Cannot check leaf certificate revocation status
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully.

C:\Temp\certs>
```

It got also pass for endentity certificate but still make external connection.

```
....
Cert is an End Entity certificate
Leaf certificate revocation check passed
CertUtil: -verify command completed successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

If you disable network communication (so, for example, non-hostfile DNS can't be contacted), is the output different?

> copied certutil.exe from another server where no such issue, compared hashes, launched but the same.

Can you clarify? You mean you copied an alternate version of certutil.exe from a different server and did not see the same behavior?

If so, there is a documented issue with certutil.exe in the exact build of Windows Server 2016 you're running, described here:

- https://www.pkisolutions.com/certutil-bug-in-windows-server-2016-fails-to-enumerate-issuance-application-policies-and-oids/

In that case, the error was a failure to enumerate or verify certificate policies enforced by the issuing CA, but since the Microsoft recommendation is to:

> copy the certutil (and the accompanying certutil.exe.mui) file from the System32 folder on either a Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2019 or Windows 10 machine. Place the files and the certificate file you’re wanting to check in a separate folder and run it from there.

...you might want to validate the behavior on other versions of Windows Server or with other versions of certutil.